# Is it possible to discard results with higher score than a given threshold in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the same way that there is a [`min_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-min-score.html) parameter to discard results with small scores, is there a way to discard results with higher score than a given value?

I use item price to calculate the score, but I need to do a query that ensures the price is between some limits (max and min). The price is calculated using function_score field function summing several fields.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first idea was to use the post_filter with a range query, but the [_score is not available in the post_filter](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20131)

But in the meanwhile, as a workaround, just define a script_score in order to exclude higher scores:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        ...
      },
      "script_score" : {
        "script" : {
          "params": {
            "max_score": 10
           },
           "source": "_score > params.max_score ? 0 : _score"
         }
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ibexit. This is exactly what I was trying to prevent, since scripts are slower, but it seems there is not better solution.

Comment: When you are calculating _score based on price out of serveral fields, are you able to precalculate the _score while indexing using ingest pipelienes for example? If so, you'll have a field i the doc, and you'll be a lot faster in searching and the range filter query will work too - have a look on it if speed matters.